# How to change the color of numbers for a theme?

Tags: themes, numbers

Is there a way to set the color of numbers differently to that of regular text?

for example, numbers such as: `1`, `2F`, `2.0f`, `0x1234`.

Can this be changed by a theme author?
If not, how can this be modified?

Comment: You might want to checkout [`highlight-numbers`](https://github.com/Fanael/highlight-numbers) package

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan, thanks - worth adding as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve highlighting of numbers in the buffers using [`highlight-numbers`](https://github.com/Fanael/highlight-numbers) package. The face used for numbering is `highlight-numbers-number` and it inherits from `font-lock-constant-face`.

For a `deftheme` the entry can be written as:

```
'(highlight-numbers-number ((t (:foreground "#f0ad6d"))))
```